# Uploading a bitmap with idHTTP from a Delphi 10.3 multidevice app

Tags: http, delphi, upload, idhttp

I have read many related posts about sending data with idHTTP but still I can't manage it.
I use this code :

**updated**

```
procedure TTabbedForm.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    fName       : string;
     mStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
    fName := 'image.jpg';
    mStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    myImage.Bitmap.SaveToStream(mStream);
    mStream.Position := 0;
    try
            IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';
            IdHTTP1.PUT('http://www.example.com/'+fName, mStream);
    finally
            mStream.free;
    end;
end;
```

but i receive the error "Method not allowed".
What i'm doing wrong, please ?

Comment: Either you have the URL incorrect, or the server does not allow Put for the URL you are using.

Comment: You need to specify a complete url, including the leading `http://` or `https://` scheme component

Comment: Actually i have include http:// in URL but the stackoverflow's editor doesn't allow it. So i didn't show it. I think that the server doesn't allow to use put command. Maybe allow post command but in this case how can i upload a stream ?

Comment: @JimPapas `TIdHTTP` has overloads of its `Post()` method for posting streams. But you need to know which kind of stream to use. Does the server allow posting raw data, or does it need to be wrapped in MIME? it makes a big difference. What does your server actually expect? Is it documented? Is it a public server we can look at?

Comment: Remmy I want do upload streams to this URL 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U9wTzrHmttbo1tQrwsTjcdXsboKG40Ah'

Answer (score 1):

For uploads to Google Drive, some additional steps are required. For example, the HTTP POST request must include a **auth token** which in turn is provided to you only after authentication (log in with a Google account). For Google Drive you must also use secure connections (https) which require SSL libraries such as OpenSSL.

[Example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/simple-upload#example_sending_a_simple_upload_request) from the API docs:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE]
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]

[JPEG_DATA]
```

The file simple upload API for Google Drive is documented here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/simple-upload

---

**Update**

Try this example, it requires a valid auth token:

```
procedure TDriveAPITest.Run;
var
  PostData: TStream;
  Response: string;
begin
  PostData := TFileStream.Create('test.png', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
      IdHTTP.HTTPOptions := IdHTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException];
      IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]';

      Response := IdHTTP.Post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media', PostData);

      if IdHTTP.ResponseCode = 200 then begin
        WriteLn('Response: ' + Response);
      end else begin
        WriteLn('Error: ' + IdHTTP.ResponseText);
      end;
    finally
      IdHTTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    PostData.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Output:

```
Error: HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: I find it difficult to convert the example into delphi code. If somebody can give some help i'll appreciate it

Comment: Firtsly, i want to thank you for your response.
I tried your code (with minor changes) and i recive the error message : socket Error #10053 Software caused connection abort. I modified your code as below :

Comment: if not imageEdit.Bitmap.IsEmpty then begin
         mStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
         ImageEdit.Bitmap.SaveToStream(mStream);
         mStream.Position := 0;
         try
      IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions := IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException];
      IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]');

      Response := IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1', mStream);
      if IdHTTP1.ResponseCode = 200 then begin ... else .....;

Comment: @JimPapas the program uses secure connections (https), so it needs the OpenSSL libraries

Comment: Yes, i have them in app's directory and i have assigned an idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 to idHTTP1

Comment: See my update, I fixed the URL (without " HTTP/1.1")

Comment: Now doesn't show error but returns Response ='' and responseText='401 Unauthorized'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189266/discussion-between-mjn-and-jimpapas).